# How to open a specific page in a word document through excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to open a specific page(say:Page 13) in a word document from the web Server using Excel Vba commandbutton.

I have tried with the below Code and here I am able to open the word document but not able to open direct the page number as required. I am not understanding where I am going wrong.

```
Private Sub cmdin_Click()

    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")

    wordApp.documents.Open "https://tr1.sharepoint.com/sites.docs"
    wordApp.Visible = True

    Set wordApp = Nothing

    wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=13 'Page number

    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Page").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you're opening from Excel it doesn't know that `wdGoToBookmark` is enum -1.  Try this: `wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Goto What:=-1, Name:=13`  Reference [enum list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdgotoitem)

Comment: Two things: 1, you can't set `wordApp` to nothing and then immediately try to use it the following line!! 2, I don't think you're able to access `ActiveDocument` via vba excel, I think you'll have to qualify it a little differently

Comment: I think it'd be `wordApp.ActiveDocument`

Comment: You are right!! It worked exactly as i required. Thank you very much.

Comment: I want to know why bookmark is given as -1 (wdGoToBookmark is enum -1)

Comment: Excel's VBA does not have access to all of the enums that Word's VBA does. If you were using Word VBA it could easily understand `wdGoToBookmark` represents `-1`, but Excel doesn't https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdgotoitem